# How to simplify $\frac{1}{3^{-2}}$ properly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Saw how it was simplified and I was wondering what allows you to rewrite this as $3^2 = 9$?

Comment: To the power of a negative number, is the same as taking the inverse. So $1/3=3^{-1}$

Comment: And the inverse function is an involution which means the inverse of the inverse takes you back to the starting value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\frac{1}{3^{-2}}=\frac{1}{3^{-2}}\cdot 1 = \frac{1}{3^{-2}}\cdot\frac{3^2}{3^2}=\frac{1\cdot 3^2}{3^{-2}\cdot 3^2}=\frac{3^2}{3^{-2+2}}=\frac{3^2}{3^0}=\frac{3^2}{1}=3^2$

In general, you can skip many of these steps and use the result $x^n=\frac{1}{x^{-n}}$ for any nonzero $x$.

Comment: In general, $a^{-b}= \frac{1}{a^b}$ so $\frac{1}{a^{-b}}= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a^b}}= a^b$

Comment: I recall trying (!) to tutor a younger cousin, who was so intent on simplifying that if we got to something like $\frac {1}{3^{-2}}\cdot \frac {3^2}{3^2}$ he would insist on simplifying it back to $\frac {1}{3^{-2}}\cdot 1.$

Comment: To that I would respond with a metaphor that to move a chess piece like a rook from one corner of the board to the other, we can choose to go vertically before horizontally or vice versa and both are equally correct and help us accomplish our goal.  In the same way, while simplifying we have multiple options.  There are many times multiple ways in which we can simplify, some of them will help us get to our goal, others may take us back where we started.  Keep your eye on the goal and what might help.  Its like a puzzle some times.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{3^{-2}}=3^{-(-2)}=3^2=3\times3=9$

Take a look [here](http://mathematics.laerd.com/maths/indices-intro.php) to know about laws of indices